# How to convert Neo4j Result to GraphJSON

Tags: neo4j

I want to use GraphJSON format in Alchemy.js for visualization . After getting the Result of CQL execution , I want to convert the Result data to GraphJSON format . Is there some API available or I will have to iterate the collection and create the GraphJSON format?. I am using Java API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an demo app that queries Neo4j and returns graphjson to render with alchemy.js

you can find it here:

http://jexp.github.io/cy2neo

running against an non-authenticated local server by default

this is the code that's used to create the graph-json

https://github.com/jexp/cy2neo/blob/master/scripts/neo.js#L36