# export whole Neo4j database / cypher result to GraphJSON

Tags: json, database, neo4j, export

I´ve already had a look at different post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585768/how-to-convert-neo4j-result-to-graphjson) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277838/from-neo4j-to-graphjson-with-ruby) but nothing seems to be answered 100%. 
My current problem is, that I want to visualyze - and ideally - analyze my Neo4j-Graph with a library (or software/tool). 
The database-server is running on a remote (virtual) server and it seems that there is no chance to export the database to a format where I can work on with. 
I´ve tried exporting the graph in a .graphml-file to import this file in Gephi, but Gephi doesn´t find the properties. Gephi-streaming with apoc-procedures and the graph-streaming plugin also does not work, because it´s a remote server (also with the tool mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32596290/5534808)).
Now I´m currently testing around with Alchemy.js... So far, so good. But as it seems there´s no way to export the graph/query to the GraphJson-format? 
Is there really no "easy" way to export the data?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would proceed

Run this query from the post you mentioned in the Neo4j Browser or in any bolt driver:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
WITH collect(
    {
        source: id(a),
        target: id(b),
        caption: type(r)
    }
) AS edges
RETURN edges
```

Now that you have loaded the data, you can simply download it as JSON using download button.(if you are using bolt driver ignore)
[image: download]

Either you manually downloaded JSON from Neo4j Browser or you are using bolt driver, you will end up with something like this.

```
{
  "columns": [
    "edges"
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "row": [
        [
          {
            "source": 31288,
            "target": 152,
            "caption": "HAS_PAYMENT_METHOD"
          }
        ]
      ],
      "meta": [
        null
      ],
      "graph": {
        "nodes": [

        ],
        "relationships": [

        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Now all you have to is to filter out `data.row` results and you are done. Probably using bolt driver is the better choice as you have to clean up data anyway and it doesnt run into issues with returning a lots of data to the browser(it might crash).

Update: added python version

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase

driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j", "neo4j"))


session = driver.session()


result = session.run("MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) WITH collect({source: id(a),target: id(b),caption: type(r)}) AS edges RETURN edges")

for record in result:
    print(record["edges"])
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If it is only a node without relationships, do you return only source ID ?